# issue with running javafx jar file

Tags: javafx

hope you all safe and well

I made a jar file like this, it's JavaFX jar, I putted the SDK inside the file
[image of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qVOj.png)

also in the run, I made these arguments

```
@echo off

start "" java --module-path "javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml -jar ShapeEditor.jar

exit
```

it works well on my computer, but when I moved it to another computer, cmd just appears and shutdown itself for no reason, I wish if someone could help me with it!.
this is my first ever JavaFX file, so I'm new to the whole concept

--udpdate:
i created the jar file by adding jar file to articats tab in intelJ [as in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofEC3.png)
, then went to build and built the jar file, added icons in the folder along with the fx SDK, and made a batch file to make run arguments as mentioned above, ran it and no problem, moved it to another windows 10 pc, ran it and a windows appears momentarily then shutdown

Comment: There is likely an exception that you can't see because the console closes too quickly. Try to launch the JAR file from the console and make it use the current window for output, or have the process log the standard output/error streams to a file. If there is an exception, what does it say?

Comment: Hi, i tried to make this "" set LOGFILE=batch.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG

start "" java --module-path "javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml -jar ShapeEditor.jar --module-path "javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml -jar ShapeEditor.jar ""
, it still not working, and no log is created what so ever, just opens and close in mere of secends, can it be becuase the java file is not specefic? and if so , could you adjuest the aruments so that it targets a java sdk inside the same file

Comment: i also tried to run it via cmd, after i installed java on it, a windows appear momentairly and then shutdown, nothing else, what's weird that it works with no problem on my pc

Comment: Can you include a [mre] in your question, along with the steps you took to create the JAR file and what operating system(s) are involved?